# Populated Dropdown list when radio Button is checked using Jquery & Ajax on Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends i get stuck when i want to create drop down menu based on checked radio button, No error and nothing happen here, whats wrong with my code ?

this is the code

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Jenis Kegiatan : </label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <?php $no=1; ?>
                        @foreach ($jkData as $jk => $val)
                        <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="jk_id" id="jk_id{{$no++}}" value="{{$jk}}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="jk_id{{$no++}}">
                            {{$val}}
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Komponen Kegiatan : </label>
                    <select class="form-control select2bs4 " name="kk_id" id="kk_id" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option disabled="true" selected="true">--- Komponen Kegiatan ---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

and this is the Jquery code

```
    script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('select[name="jk_id"]:checked').on('change', function () {
            var jk = jQuery(this).val();
            if (jk) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'pengajuan/getKK/' +jk,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        jQuery('select[name="kk_id"]').empty();
                        jQuery.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $('select[name="kk_id"]').append('<option value="' +
                                key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('select[name="kk_id"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `select[name="jk_id"]:checked` this does not seems right!!! Can you elaborate more whats you expected out or provide a minimal working example ?

Comment: like this for example the radio button is a class name of student, and the dropdown list is for student name, when i checked radio button for example i select Anubis Class, and then combobox or drop down list is auto fill name of student from anubis class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** using the right input radio in your onchange function. This `select[name="jk_id"]:checked`  -`syntax` is not correct

Change your `jQuery` code to this below and it should work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var jk = jQuery(this).val();
    if (jk) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'pengajuan/getKK/' + jk,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          jQuery('select[name="kk_id"]').empty();
          jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="kk_id"]').append('<option value="' +
              key + '">' + value + '</option>');
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('select[name="kk_id"]').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @JuMa Happy to hear that. Happy coding.